# Parsing C# dynamic string

Tags: c#, string

I am getting a string returned to my application from my gateway processor. The string contents are:

```
ssl_result=0
ssl_result_message=APPROVAL
ssl_txn_id=9621F9AD-E49E-4003-91BD-5C1B08569959
ssl_approval_code=N54032
ssl_cvv2_response=
ssl_avs_response=
ssl_invoice_number=123-ABC
ssl_amount=5.00
ssl_card_number=00*******0000
ssl_exp_date=0000
ssl_email=test@test.com
```

The ssl_result_message could be either "APPROVAL" or "DECLINED". I need to be able to parse the string to determine what the message was and if approved, what the ssl_approval_code is. The problem I am having is these values will be dynamic.

Comment: um, so what is your question?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "dynamic"? Thus far this seems like a very basic string parsing problem -- what have you tried that isn't working for you?

Comment: Assuming that Googling for "string parsing" doesn't help you, try "regular expression".

Comment: By dynamic I mean the values that are sent back from my gateway processor. I4V's solution worked and makes perfect sense. I may have been over thinking the whole thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var dict = File.ReadLines(filename)
           .Select(line=>line.Split(new char[]{'='},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
           .ToDictionary(parts=>parts[0], parts=>parts.Length>1 ? parts[1] : "");

 Console.WriteLine(dict["ssl_result_message"]);
```

if it is in a string, then

```
var dict = text.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .Select(line=>line.Split(new char[]{'='},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
           .ToDictionary(parts=>parts[0], parts=>parts.Length>1 ? parts[1] : "");
```